# Cannot make Python request from Django hosting

Tags: python, django, cookies, request, python-requests

I want to make a site that will get some information from authorised page.
There is a web-page with form where I enter cookies and some other data.
Using them I want to get text of web page, but I can get it only if made get-request with my cookies.
So when i make this request using python shell everything is good - I get text of authorised page.

```
p = requests.post('https://lalala.com/public140466996',headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.92 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.6.689.34","Cookies":"somecookies","Host":"lalala.com"})
```

But when I try to make it on hosting web server using Django I get a response with not authorised page

```
def index(request):
if request.method =='POST':

    data = SearchForm(request.POST)
    if data.is_valid():
        group = data.cleaned_data.get('group')
        remixsid = data.cleaned_data.get('remixsid')
        post_number = data.cleaned_data.get('post_number')
        comment = data.cleaned_data.get('comment')

        p = requests.post('https://lalala.com/public140466996',headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.92 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.6.689.34","Cookies":"somecookies","Host":"lalala.com"})
        return HttpResponse(p.text)
```

Could you help and explain why i have this problem?
Maybe hosting don't add cookies or add something that allowed?

Comment: What are you using at Front end?

Comment: I just  have a template with form and nothing more
But where is the link between front end and my request
Or maybe i don't understand something

Comment: have you added `<form action="/admin/start/" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}` while making request?

Comment: try addign `p.raise_for_status()`. What is the HTTP error you are getting? it might be an HTTPS issue.  And `lalala.com` might not like the fact you are using the same cookies from two different countries and block you as a security measure.

Comment: I don't have any errors. I can't authorise. Maybe it's really because request from other country and lalala.com block cookies. What can I do with this?

Comment: what will change `<form action="/admin/start/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}` ??